# Can I change the V-Net of an existing NIC?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-virtual-network

An Azure resource NIC (Network Interface) is initially attached to a V-Net while created. Can I change the V-Net later? If so how can I achieve that through Portal or Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, It is not possible/supported to change directly a VNET for an existing NIC. But it's easy to change the subnet of the NIC. You can find the network interface---IP configurations---choosing the subnets on the portal.

[image]

With the PowerShell, you can get more details from [How to change Subnet and Virtual Network for Azure Virtual Machines (ASM & ARM)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2016/03/13/how-to-change-subnet-and-virtual-network-for-azure-virtual-machines-asm-arm/)